# Flutter AutoSizeTextField multiline labelText

Tags: flutter, dart, label, textfield, multiline

the `labeltext` field I set for `AutoSizeTextField` is insufficient. Is there a way to do multiline?

```
AutoSizeTextField(
                                ...
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                    ),
                                    labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                        .translate('total_spent'),
                                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black,),
                                    hintText: spent.toString(),
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    ...
```

[image]

Comment: What about just using `TextField`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just couldn't set the autosize setting for you in the textfield. My question is labeltext.

Comment: is it ok to decrease fontSize on `labelStyle`?

Answer (score 0):

`labelText` size depends on `AutoSizeTextField`'s font size if we don't specify the font size on `labelStyle`.

You can solve it by reducing the `fontSize` on `labelStyle` or separate the hit text using `\n`, `label\ntext`.

Or providing enough width to `AutoSizeTextField`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to use this font size. I tried \n solutions but label text overflow on texfield.